# Status bar doesnt respect 'barStyle' property

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, statusbar

In React Native, using the following:

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor={config.colors.backgroundGray} barStyle="dark-content" />
```

works well. However when navigating to a different screen, even though the above is the only instance of `StatusBar` used in the entire app, the status bar style turns to what essentially is "light-content" on its own. Rendering the StatusBar component deeper in again seems to yield no results.

The **backgroundColor** is controllable however. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that the background color of StatusBar is applied globally, but the style is only applicable to that screen?

Comment: I think default barStyle is "light-content", so that's what's applied when no <StatusBar/> component is given.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply Statusbar's own function to `App.js.`

App.js

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content', true);
```

> static setBarStyle(style: StatusBarStyle, [animated]: boolean)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you choose one?

Comment: imma try it now, i wonder why it is i would have to do that though. wouldnt that mean that the api is wrong and documentation needs revisiting then? will get back to you real soon to mark as accepted

Comment: I think you need to style the StatusBar like my answer because you want to change the overall design rather than change the StatusBar design on one screen.

Comment: however even when i do it per screen its only the style property thats not affected wheras the background is. the API is definitely problematic in that sense

Comment: It seems good to post this question on Github and discuss it with the React native developer. Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: Actually even with this approach no, the same issue remains. Have not yet looked at iOS but this is definitely happening on android

Comment: If it works on the iPhone, there will be a difference in how it works, and if it doesn't, there seems to be something wrong with the module.

Comment: it would appear so, i've seen people in the past complaining about it as well but no clear cut solution. iphone works fine for me as well, android is very problematic

Comment: I think it would be better to talk to the module developer.

Comment: thank you. i think its best not to mark as accepted but i found a workaround which does work that i ll post here